AWS IAM Role AuthFailure in Newly Opted-In Region
I have a question regarding AWS IAM roles and newly opted-in regions.
Suppose I create a role and attach a policy to it in one of my AWS accounts. Later, I opt into a new region in this AWS account.
Now, if this role is assumed by an EC2 instance in another account, would the role have access to the new region?
I am encountering an issue where I get the following AuthFailure error when trying to perform actions in the newly opted-in region:
AuthFailure: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials

This error only occurs for the newly opted-in region. Could someone help me understand why this is happening and how I can resolve it?
